# Script for indicating order history - Tradeview Pine

Tags: import, trading, pine-script

I want to indicate historical trades in tradingview charts via a script based on information on time and price for entry and close.

My best idea is to search through "time" to find matches for entry and close, and then change the background color according to short or long position or draw a horizontal line. However, this seems not optimal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd implement that in the next way:

```
//@version=3
strategy("Background changing", overlay=true)

NONE = 0
LONG = 1000
SHORT = -1000

position = NONE
position := nz(position[1], NONE)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("LongEntryId", strategy.long)
    position := LONG


if (close < high[1])
    strategy.close("LongEntryId")
    position := NONE


getColor(state) =>
    state == LONG ? green :
  state == SHORT ? red :
  white


bgcolor(color=getColor(position))
```

Or you can put arrows to the chart:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", overlay=true)

order = 0
if time >= timestamp(2018, 1, 10, 0, 0)
    order := 1
if time == timestamp(2018, 1, 17, 0, 0)
    order := -1
plotarrow(order)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michel_T. I see, I need to be more specific. I'm not testing a strategy, but would like to "import" my old trades from the ETXCapital-broker. Basically I  need to convert a spreadsheet with entry and exit - time and -price to to a Pine-script which can indicate/draw those trades on the nice charts of tradingview.

Comment: So you have a list a trades by times and you'd like to put signs to the chart?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to make it easy to review my historical trades, which I can export from my broker in CSV-format.

Comment: I only know the way to implement in via checking the timestamp for every trade and putting an arrow in places of orders. I've updated my answer. Yes, that's verbose, but there's no another way to do such task.